# boost::multi_index_container: Find index iterator from other index iterator

Tags: boost, multi-index

I have a multi_index_container indexed by 2 indexes. I'm able to find the value by one of them, but is it possible to find the iterator from the other corresponding index?

Example:

```
struct ById{};
struct ByName{};

typedef multi_index_container<
MyStruct,
indexed_by<
    ordered_unique<tag<ById>, member< MyStruct, int, &MyStruct::id> >,
    ordered_non_unique<tag<BySalary>, member< MyStruct, int, &MyStruct::salary> >
>
> MyStructsContainer;

typedef MyStructsContainer::index<ById>::type MyStructsContainerById;
typedef MyStructsContainer::index<BySalary>::type MyStructsContainerBySalary;
```

....

```
MyStructsContainerById& byId = myStructsContainer.get<ById>();
MyStructsContainerById::iterator itById = byId.find(3);
```

The question is, is there an easy way to find the corresponding:

```
MyStructsContainerByName::iterator itBySalary
```

which points to the exact same value ( *itById) ?

Thanks,
Kalin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `boost::multi_index::project`

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/multi_index_container.html#projection

> Given a `multi_index_container` with indices i1 and i2, we say than an i1-iterator `it1` and an i2-iterator `it2` are equivalent if:
>
> - `it1==i1.end()` AND `it2==i2.end()`
>
> OR
>
> - `it1` and `it2` point to the same element.

In your sample

```
auto& byId = myStructsContainer.get<ById>();
auto itById = byId.find(3);
```

you could use

```
MyStructsContainerByName::iterator itBySalary = project<1>(
      myStructsContainer, itById);
```

or indeed:

```
auto itBySalary = project<BySalary>(myStructsContainer, itById);
```

with exactly the same effect

Comment: One more question. What is the complexity of "project" Constant? I hope it wont do some iterations and so on...

Comment: `MyStructsContainer` is defined as it's first index (`ById`, or index 0)

Comment: @KalliMan Well. The page I linked says "Complexity: constant". In ***bold letters***. What more do you want to know?