# About boost multiindex default elements ordering

Tags: boost, multi-index

I noticed that by default the items in multi_index_container are sorted by the first index.

Example:

```
typedef multi_index_container<
MyStruct,
indexed_by<
    ordered_unique<member< MyStruct, int, &MyStruct::id> >,
    ordered_non_unique<member< MyStruct, int, &MyStruct::salary> >
>
> MyStructsContainer;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MyStructsContainer myStructsContainer;

    MyStructsContainer::iterator it1 = myStructsContainer.emplace(MyStruct{ 1, 100 }).first;
    assert(distance(it1, myStructsContainer.end()) == 1 );
    MyStructsContainer::iterator it2 = myStructsContainer.emplace(MyStruct{ 2, 20 }).first;
    assert(distance(it1, myStructsContainer.end()) == 2);
}
```

My question is - is this a documented, a "well known" behavior, and I can can rely on it? Or it is just a side effect?

I have a list of structures "MyStruct", and they should be sorted by their ID. But for some reason I have to know their numeric index from the sorted queue. If I can use this approach this will make unnecessary to make a find over the 1-st ordered index and then std::distance.

Thanks,
Kalin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can rely on it.  From the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#multiple_sort):

> The functionality of index #0 can be accessed directly from a multi_index_container object without using `get<0>()`: for instance, `es.begin()` is equivalent to `es.get<0>().begin()`.

Comment: Funny thing is, I [already answered that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28309136/boostmulti-index-container-find-index-iterator-from-other-index-iterator#comment44982530_28309574) the other day. Seems OP upgraded the coment to a question anyways...